# UITextField IOS7 not setting font color during input

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

I have some simple code that worked fine under `iOS6`. In a `UITextField` when the event `editingDidBegin` arrived I executed a simple piece of code that changed the color of the text that was entered:

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Although this code is executed, the text color does not change to red, but remains unchanged at its default color as the text is being entered.

If I call this method on `editingDidEnd`, the text is entered in the default color, but changes to red when editingDidEnd kicks off the same piece of code:

```
textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It seems as though I can not change the `textColor` property when the `textField` is the first responder.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Text field or view? You seem to use both interchangeably.

Comment: It is a UITextField. I will need to change the first line of the question.

Comment: Then please update the title, question, and tags so all reference to "text view" are "text field".

Answer (score 0):

You should do some subclassing for that

Here is a good solution that works both on ios6 and ios7
http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/how-change-colour-uitextfields-placeholder-text-ios7-and-still-support-ios6

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of accomplishing this. I used the UITextField delegate method and added the following code. Seems like my original method should have worked moving to IOS7, but this now works fine.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[textField setValue:[UIColor redColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

This will change the place holder color of `UITextField`,